# Prevent a Tomcat web app from accessing the internet

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I need to restore a backup of jamfPro (a tomcat webapp with mySQL database) to retrieve some data that no longer exists in my production instance. I can't have this restored backup reaching out to the internet as it could invalidate the vendor tokens in prod (example: Apple VPP/DEP tokens).

I usually restore backups to an air-gapped Mac workstation then access the app via localhost in a browser, but I'm wondering if there is a better way. Can I set Tomcat to start the webapp, but disallow it from reaching out to resources on the internet?

Comment: How about using the host firewall?

Comment: great suggestion! I don't know how to do that though... ::to the googles::